# Wordpress Menu UL height

Tags: css, wordpress, list, cufon

I have some pretty good experince coding my own UL's but I'm relatively new to wordpress. Confusing to me to work backwards especially when I can't see the html. Anyway I'm using the cufon WP plugin to change the font in the menu. but....with the size I want the font, it shrinks the list item as well as the a:hover. There is somehting in the padding i presume, but I can't find it. you can see what I mean here http://www.thedailyminx.com

here is the menu's css

```
#navbar {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background: #bfbcc6;
    color: #000000;
    width: 978px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'jc-hand';
    margin: 15px auto 15px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
    }

/*** ESSENTIAL STYLES ***/
.menu, .menu * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    }
.menu {
    line-height: 1.0;
    }
.menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
.menu ul ul, ul.menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    width: 160px; /* left offset of submenus need to match (see below) */
    }
.menu ul li ul li, ul.menu ul li {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
.menu li:hover {
    visibility: inherit; /* fixes IE7 'sticky bug' */
    }
.menu li {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    }
.menu a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    }
.menu li:hover ul,
.menu li.sfHover ul {
    left: 0;
    top: 30px; /* match top ul list item height */
    z-index: 99;
    }
ul.menu li:hover li ul,
ul.menu li.sfHover li ul {
    top: -9999px;
    }
ul.menu li li:hover ul,
ul.menu li li.sfHover ul {
    left: 160px; /* match ul width */
    top: 0;
    }
ul.menu li li:hover li ul,
ul.menu li li.sfHover li ul {
    top: -9999px;
    }
ul.menu li li li:hover ul,
ul.menu li li li.sfHover ul {
    left: 160px; /* match ul width */
    top: 0;
    }

/*** SKIN ***/
.menu .current_page_item a,
.menu .current_page_ancestor a,
.menu .current-menu-item a,
.menu .current-cat a {
    background: #333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-left: 1px solid #333333;
    border-right: 1px solid #333333;
    }
.menu li .current_page_item a, .menu li .current_page_item a:hover,
.menu li .current-menu-item a, .menu li .current-menu-item a:hover,
.menu li .current-cat a, .menu li .current-cat a:hover {
    background: #333333 !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    }
.menu {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    }
.menu a {
    color: #000000;
    background: none;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 12px 0px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.1px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    }
.menu li li a {
    display: block;
    background: #F5F5F5 !important;
    color: #000000 !important;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    border-right: none !important;
    border-left: none !important;
    }
.menu li, .menu li li, .menu li li li {
    background: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
.menu li:hover, .menu li.sfHover {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
.menu a:focus, .menu a:hover, .menu a:active {
    background: #333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-right: 1px solid #333333;
    border-left: 1px solid #333333;
    outline: 0;
    }
.menu li li:hover, .menu li li.sfHover {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
.menu li li a:focus, .menu li li a:hover, .menu li li a:active {
    background: #EEEEEE !important;
    color: #333333 !important;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    }
```

can anyone help me out?
Thanks
Greg

Comment: Not exactly sure what change you are trying to make.  I notice that on your site the cufon font runs out of the grey box.  Do you want the background grey to be taller?  Do you want the font to be smaller?

Comment: Also, you may be interested in using Firefox's Firebug tool, Chrome's developer tools feature, or IE9's Developer Tools to examine the HTML and CSS that your WordPress install produces.

Answer (score 0):

ditch the inline `height` styling of `cufon` and set it in your stylesheet to `30px`

Comment: thanks for your asnwer. How can I get rid of the height styling of Cufon?

Comment: haha, I have no idea. That's the rub with WP. You could also change your `navbar` height to 25px;